# JavaScripts's Number.MIN_VALUE is equal to 0

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a library in JS that process some binary data. I wanted to write a test using `Number.MIN_VALUE` but it seems to be equal to 0:

```
> Number.MIN_VALUE
< 0
> Number.MIN_VALUE > 0
< false
```

Using Chrome 64 on Linux 4.15 64-bit (KDE Neon, custom kernel 4.15.3-ext73-55.3-intelstandard). Same result with Firefox 59 and Node.js 7.10.0 and 8.10.0.

On other machine (also 64-bit Linux) with Node.js 8.10.0 it returns valid value `5e-324`.

Similar tests on C++ (gcc 7.3) looks good, gives valid results: `std::numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min();` returns valid `0x01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`.

Comment: My Firefox 58.0.1 (64-bit, macOS) gives 5e-324. Same with Chrome 64.0.3282 and Safari 11.0.3, all 64-bit and macOS.

Comment: Here `Number.MIN_VALUE > 0` returns `true` for `Chrome 65.0.3325.146`, `Firefox 58.0.2` on Linux (4.15.8-1-ARCH).

Comment: Do they have different CPUs?

Comment: Mine machine: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz, the other one is an old C2D

Comment: Same result with other generic kernels, it's some OS setting? I thought that `MIN_VALUE` is const, I can't rewrite it, but for some reason it's equal to 0 in all browsers.

Comment: You wrote `but it seems to be equal to 0` so does `Number.MIN_VALUE === 0` show `true`?

Comment: Yes, triple = gives the same result

Comment: Same thing on my home machine with Kubuntu 17.10 :/

Comment: Ok, libstdc++ was the reason, Netex73 kernel installer replaces it with it's own version which contains this bug.